# Finding and flagging overlapping dates between grouped records using only SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble coming up with a good solution to this problem. I have the table below:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Column1Id | Column2Id | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|       120 |        12 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |
|       120 |        41 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |
|       120 |        55 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |
|       120 |        56 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |
|      3293 |        41 | 2014-07-20 | 2014-07-26 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

What I want to do is check all records grouped by Column1Id and Column2Id and see if the StartDate and EndDate overlap on any days, if so, it should set a bit to 1 else 0. In the example table the result should be this:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
| Column1Id | Column2Id | StartDate  |  EndDate   | HasDateOverlap |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
|       120 |        12 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |              0 |
|       120 |        41 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |              1 |
|       120 |        55 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |              0 |
|       120 |        56 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |              0 |
|      3293 |        41 | 2014-07-20 | 2014-07-26 |              1 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

The constraint I have for the solution is that it must use only SQL (no stored procedures, UDFs etc...)

You can assume I have a query that does:

```
SELECT ColumnId1, ColumnId2, StartDate, EndDate
FROM   Table1
```

To retrieve the first table.

**EDIT:**

A date is overlapped when, for the same Column2Id, there are days that overlap between the StartDate and EndDate for different Column1Id values.

So in first table, Column2Id value 41 has two different Column1Id values (120, 3293) those StartDate and EndDates overlap (2014-07-20 to 2014-07-26 overlap on 2014-07-13 to 2014-07-26).

**EDIT 2**
More detailed.

First table relevant records to check are these two:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Column1Id | Column2Id | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|       120 |        41 | 2014-07-13 | 2014-07-26 |
|      3293 |        41 | 2014-07-20 | 2014-07-26 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Why? Because the other records only have 1 record key (Column1Id, Column2Id).

So from these two records I can see that the Column1Id value is different, I need to check the StartDate and EndDate on these records (could be more than 2 records to check against) to see if there is an overlap (in either direction).

```
2014-07-13 to 2014-07-26
2014-07-20 to 2014-07-26
```

These date ranges overlap because any of the days in either range are included in the other range. July 20th, with Column1Id 3293, fits into July 13th to July 26th with Column1Id 120.

Comment: I'm not following how you are indicating that a range is overlapped.

Comment: @paqogomez Sorry, I've added an explanation as to how a date overlap occurs.

Comment: I have the answer, but it's hard to test with this stupid tablet. Until I get my hands on the PC, try solving the problem with a self join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a2415/2)**

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Table1 t2
      WHERE t1.StartDate < t2.EndDate
        AND t2.StartDate < t1.EndDate
        AND t1.Column2Id = t2.Column2Id   --to accommodate edited question
        AND t1.Column1Id <> t2.Column1Id  --to accommodate edited question
    ) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS HasDateOverlap
FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: I cannot see how this query would not produce the sample results that OP has indicated.  Could you offer some explanation?

Comment: @Anon . . . Good logic, but doesn't answer the OP's question.  S/he just clarified the question with the edit.  You should look at that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's harder to hit a moving target.

Comment: @Anon I'm not getting the results I'd expect. I might not be explaining the overlap properly. Given just the input I gave using your SQL I get no overlap flag for any records. I should get an overlap on 2 records.

Comment: @Anon Seems to be working. I noticed that the last logic statement was  t1.Column1Id <> t1.Column1Id (typo) and should have been t1.Column1Id <> t2.Column1Id